# Using an initrd/initramfs as the root filesystem

Tags: linux, initramfs, root-filesystem, initrd

In Android, the initial RAM disk stays mounted throughout the entirety of the time the operating system is running. No `switch_root`/`pivot_root` takes place.

Is this kind of setup easy to pull off with a desktop distribution of Linux? For instance, could I just make a few changes to the `cpio.gz` file generated by `mkinitcpio` on Arch Linux to prevent it from switching the root device and to bind mount directories like `/etc`, `/usr`, and such within the RAM-based root filesystem?

Comment: Unwise specifically for e. g. `/etc` and `/usr`.  Anything in the RAM disk would be destroyed upon reboot or shutdown, making persistent host configuration or persistent data storage quite problematic.